# Return a Type Even if Type is void

Tags: c++, c++14, default-value, void, return-type

I have a function: `template <typename T> T foo()`. The thing is `T` can be `void`.

If I had [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) support I'd define it like this:

```
template <typename T>
T foo() {
    if constexpr(is_same_v<T, void>) {
        return;
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

But I don't :( Is there anything I can do in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) to conditionally return `T{}`?

Comment: Nice call on the dupe.  I would not have expected a question presumably about _partial_ template specialization of a _class_ to be related, but the accepted answer is indeed exactly what's needed.